# Must @ComponentScan be placed with @Configuration? (Spring Core)

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I read inside many articles that @ComponentScan should be placed with @Configuration on top of a class. Here some references:

> we use the @ComponentScan annotation along with @Configuration
> annotation to specify the packages that we want to be scanned
> (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.zetcode") @Configuration public
> class Application { ... } (http://zetcode.com/spring/componentscan)

> The @ComponentScan annotation is used with the @Configuration
> annotation to tell Spring the packages to scan for annotated
> components. (https://dzone.com/articles/spring-component-scan)

I was curious to try if without @Configuration an exception would have been thrown. Surprisingly  everything works fine even without @Configuration. Here the code:

```
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        for (String beanDefinitionName : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanDefinitionName);
        }
    }
}
```

I had just one sample bean which got printed.

```
@Component
public class Car {

}
```

This was the output of the main method:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
appConfig
car
```

Why does it work? and why do they tell to use it with configuration? was it an old requirement?

And even more surprisingly appConfig becomes a bean, even if it does not have any particular annotation such as @Configuration or @Component. So does that mean that anything that gets put as argument of new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext() gets turned into a bean no matter what annotation does it has or has not?

I probably miss some core spring behavior which would justify this. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still using `@Configuration` together with `@ComponentScan` implicitly.  By pasing the `AppConfig.class` as param to the context, it considers it configuration. That would explain the bean created for it as well

Comment: Ok I get it now thank you. So it is not required to use @Configuration right? I can use just @ComponentScan! why do they use it then? is there another reason?

Comment: But then you have to pass the class that has the `@ComponentScan` as param. How often we create the context ourself?  So even though you are not putting the annotation, you are making it implicitly configuration anyway.  So may be document should say it is used together with Configuration class instead of `@Configuration` annotation so it covers both

Comment: @StefanoSambruna Some developers like to keep things explicit and others don't know about it :)

Comment: i also create an empty class(named `ConfigClass`) only with `@ComponentScan`, and in a junit test class like `@SpringJUnitConfig(ConfigClass.class) class MyTest`, i also can get beans. however, i don't pass `ConfigClass` as param to any context. so is there any implicit `@Configuration` in my case?